# Initializing a slice by using the var keyword

Tags: go, initialization, slice, literals

Nowadays I am learning Golang and don't understand a situation how Golang behaves.

Here it is a declaration and initialization of a slice by short hand:

```
ilist := []int{1, 2, 3}  //it works
```

on the other hand if I try to declare and initialize it with the `var` keyword, it gives an error:

```
var ilist [] int = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}  //error
```

If I initialize just a variable (not a slice) it works fine:

```
var i int = 5 // works fine
```

Why does Golang behave like this, is there any specific reason?

Comment: I am not experienced in Go, but I had a quick look at the language spec. Have you tried `var ilist []int = []int{1, 2, 3}`? A composite literal like one for a slice requires a type, in contrast to a basic literal, such as a number or a string. You may also omit the type after the var name: `var ilist = []int{1, 2, 3}`.

Comment: yes you right but still weird, because i give the all information to create composite literal on left side of declaration (var ilist [] int ) .

Answer (score 8):

> i give the all information to create composite literal

That's the thing: you **did not** give all the required information to create a composite literal. Check out the [Spec: Composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) section to see what is required.

This literal:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

This literal misses the *type* information. It could be a part of an `[]int{}` literal, it could be a part of a `[]float32{}` literal, it could even be a part of a struct literal, where the struct type has `int` fields (e.g. `type Ints struct{a,b,c,d,e int}`).

Yes, in this variable declaration

```
var ilist [] int = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}  //error
```

Only `[]int{}` literal makes sense, but that is not how Go works. Just because there is only a single type that would make this line valid, it doesn't mean you can omit it.

Note that however you may omit the type from the declaration if it can be inferred from the initialization expression, so both of these forms are valid:

```
var ilist1 []int = []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

var ilist2 = []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

But the type of `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` would be ambiguous (if it would be valid).

Also note that if you're specifying a composite literal for a type like `[][]int`, you *may* omit the type from the (sub)literals of the elements, because it is known from the type of the composite literal, so this is also valid:

```
var iilist = [][]int{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
}
```

Same goes for map literals, this is valid (was added in [Go 1.5](https://golang.org/doc/go1.5#map_literals)):

```
var imap = map[int][]int{
    1: {1, 2, 3},
    2: {4, 5, 6},
}
```

Try these on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bFTAfUBs4u).

Answer (score 1):

In go, `different names mean different types`. So when you define a variable, you must specify its type. That means, you need make sure that your assignment is a concrete type. "{}" can be more than one type, so the compilier can not find `ilist` type. BTW, some friends rise a discussion about [Proposal: Alias declarations for Go](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16339#issuecomment-258527920)